# ffmpeg - Record Server Desktop Without Connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ffmpeg, screen-capture

I set up an application which uses ffmpeg to record a desktop on an Amazon AWS EC2 instance having Windows Server 2012 R2 installed. It records the desktop and puts the result into a file.

This works as long as a Remote Desktop or TeamViewer connection is active for that particular Amazon AWS EC2 instance. As soon as I close the Remote Desktop and TeamViewer connection the recording stops and continues as soon as I reconnect.

I assume that it's because the GPU doesn't deliver frames without a display in use.

How can I make sure that frames are constantly being rendered so that I can record them?

Comment: maybe you can drop the c++ tag, irrelevant here and that can decrease your question visibility

Comment: Done. Removed the c++ tag.

Comment: https://github.com/rdp/screen-capture-recorder-to-video-windows-free/issues/7 may be useful

Answer (score 1):

for similar purpose, we are using a vnc server & client and we let the windows session opened all the time

Comment: Relying on another company's VNCserver and client is not an option for me as I am working on my own server and client.

Comment: Try to see if http://serverfault.com/questions/269438/how-to-stop-remote-desktop-from-closing-my-session-due-to-inactivity helps you

Comment: I will have a look if there are any settings that can help me. But I doubt it because these settings are about time-outs. Not about keeping a display available even without a RDP/TeamViewer connection and prevent the graphics cards from stopping to render.

Comment: This one use another trick when disconnecting http://serverfault.com/questions/205902/how-to-keep-user-logged-in-when-disconnecting-from-rdp-session